# python gui for mysql (table selection)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, user-interface, tkinter

it might seem like a wierd request, but i need to make a gui to be able to edit my database in mysql, my databse has 6 tables and i need to be able to select which table i want to edit.
so far i could only figure out how to make a gui for a specific table
how i made it:

1.define functions: insert, get, delete, update:

```
def insert():
id = e_id.get()
sex = e_sex.get()
if(id=='' or sex==''):
    messagebox.showinfo('insert status', 'all fields are required!')
else:
    con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user ='root', password='ccvvbb', database ='mydb')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into sex values('"+ id +"','" + sex +"')")
    cursor.execute("commit")
    e_id.delete(0, 'end')
    e_sex.delete(0, 'end')
    show()
    messagebox.showinfo("insert status", "inserted successfully")
    con.close()

def show():
    con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='ccvvbb', database='mydb')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from sex")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    list.delete(0, list.size())
    for row in rows:
        insertdata = str(row[0])+ '      '+ row[1]
        list.insert(list.size()+1, insertdata)
    con.close()
```

same for all the functions

2.make the gui

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
id = Label(root, text='id', font=('bold', 10))
id.place(x=40, y=30)
sex = Label(root, text='sex', font=('bold', 10))
sex.place(x=40, y=60)
e_id = Entry()
e_id.place(x=100, y=30)
e_sex = Entry()
e_sex.place(x=100, y=60)
insert = Button(root, text = 'insert', font =('bold', 10), bg = 'gray', command = insert)
insert.place (x=40, y= 120)
delete = Button(root, text = 'delete', font =('bold', 10), bg = 'gray', command = delete)
delete.place (x=100, y= 120)
update = Button(root, text = 'update', font =('bold', 10), bg = 'gray', command = update)
update.place (x=160, y= 120)
get = Button(root, text = 'get', font =('bold', 10), bg = 'gray', command = get)
get.place (x=220, y= 120)
```

[gui for table 'sex'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lpWL.png)

but i dont understand how can i make a drop down list of all my avilable tables? do i need to make a seperate python file for each table and then pick which file i want to execute using a drop down table? or do i need to define a gui (i.e root1=table1, root2=table2 and so on) and then select a gui for my table each time? what is the base way to make a table selection (ofc each table has different columns so when picking a table the columns also need to be different
maybe a dropdown table isnt the best solution? maybe making a "tab" for each table might be easier to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is no, you dont need to define gui for every table separatly.

I wrote some code that might be helpful to you:

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Table 1",
"Table 2",
"Table 3"
] #etc


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")


def clear_frame():
    """
    Used to clear window

    Returns:None

    """
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


def start_screen():
    clear_frame()
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

    w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS)
    w.pack()

    button_login = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Continue", command=lambda: picker(variable))
    button_login.pack(pady=10)


def picker(var):
    value = var.get()
    if value == "Table 1":
        first_table()
    elif value == "Table 2":
        test_table()
    else:
        print("it is else")


def first_table():
    clear_frame()

    label = Label(root, text="Id", font=('Courier', 15), fg='Green')
    label.pack(pady=5)
    id_text_box = Text(root, height=1, width=16)
    id_text_box.pack(pady=5)
    label = Label(root, text="Sex", font=('Courier', 15), fg='Green')
    label.pack(pady=5)
    sex_text_box = Text(root, height=1, width=16, fg='black', bg='white')
    sex_text_box.pack(pady=5)
    button_insert = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Insert")
    button_insert.pack(pady=5)
    button_delete = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Delete")
    button_delete.pack(pady=5)
    button_return = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Return", command=lambda: start_screen())
    button_return.pack(pady=15)


def test_table():
    clear_frame()

    label = Label(root, text="Something", font=('Courier', 15), fg='Green')
    label.pack(pady=5)
    some_text_box = Text(root, height=1, width=16)
    some_text_box.pack(pady=5)
    label = Label(root, text="Data", font=('Courier', 15), fg='Green')
    label.pack(pady=5)
    data_text_box = Text(root, height=1, width=16, fg='black', bg='white')
    data_text_box.pack(pady=5)
    button_insert = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Insert")
    button_insert.pack(pady=5)
    button_delete = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Delete")
    button_delete.pack(pady=5)
    button_return = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Return", command=lambda: start_screen())
    button_return.pack(pady=15)


start_screen()
mainloop()
```